# Override Js file with version after extension in DevTool

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, devtools

I want to override a js file in the Chrome Devtool because I want to add log or other line to semplify my debug.
I think the webapp is written in React.
Normally, for override a single file,  I just use "save for override" in the devtool and I can modify the local file.
This time the file extension include the file version, like .js?v=1111 and the devtool override doesn't work.
Does somebody know how to do in this case?

Comment: could you just remove the addition to the file extention? so make it .js instead of .js?v=1111

Comment: The webapp isn't mine, so I can't change the original file. If I remove the additional part after "save for override" in the local file it doesn't work either